# java equation of vectors

Tags: java, matrix, vector, equation

I have a matrix and few bottom lines of the matrix are same, so i wanted to just dont show them when i print the matrix. I tried 2 diffent aproaches but non of them works.

```
if (matrix[index] == matrix[index+1] {
    system.out.println("Next lines are same");
}
```

and

```
if (matrix[index].equals(matrix[index+1]) {
    system.out.println("Next lines are same");
}
```

After both ifs i add 1 to index as im showing lines of the matrix one by one

Comment: Don't you think the information what type `matrix` exactly is is kind of necessary for any help? Going by the code you posted it is an array, but we have no idea what kind of array.

Comment: ah, im sorry. I declared the matrix as int [] []

Comment: I dont think so, its same as my first example...never shows its same

Comment: yes, thank you, ill keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
 if (Arrays.equals(matrix[index], matrix[index+1]) ) {
                    ....
 }
```